# Is it possible to have 2 different versions of the ASP.NET Ajax Library running on the same page?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, asp.net-ajax

I'm using some third-party controls that use an older version of the ASP.NET Ajax library, but also would like to use some features of the newest version of said library. The problem, naturally, becomes dealing with the clashing namespaces. Is there a way to wrap the newer Ajax library in a separate namespace so I could use them independently of the third-party control's version?

Comment: I suspect that it will be far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I suspect the same, but I have to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but I doubt it will work as you expect. Javascript functions with the same name are overwritten as they are interpreted, so the last one read will be the one executed when invoked. If I were you, I would contact the third-party and tell them what your requirements are for the ASP.NET AJAX library.